# TypeError: navneliste.join is not a function

Tags: javascript

Using this code, I get a TypeError: navneliste.join is not a function. Can you explain me why?

navneliste.json:

```
{ "navn": "Kari Norrmann", "navn": "Ola Norrmann", "navn": "Per Norrmann"}
```

Oblig1Oppg3Liste.js:

```
var http = require('http'); var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {  if (req.url == '/') {
            fs.readFile('./navneliste.json', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.end('Server Error');
            } else {
                var navneliste = JSON.parse(data);

                fs.readFile('./Oblig1Oppg3HTML.html', function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        res.end('Server Error');                    
                } else {
                    var tmpl = data.toString();


                    var html = tmpl.replace('%', navneliste.join('</li><li>'));
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                    res.end(html);

                }
                });
        }
    });

}

}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) method is available for arrays and `navneliste` is not an array, is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). read the documentation for [json parse](http://JSON.parse)